# Pass values of checkboxes into an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to update someone else's Rails app. Right now, an HTML table displays values from a database. What i want is to be able to display a checkbox for each row and on submit, the values of the checkboxes are sent into an array (and the values shouldnt be "checked" or "unchecked", they should be the id's of the database row).

Heres what i have so far.

Checkbox : (message.id being a dynamic id)

```
 <%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id %>
```

And on the controller:

```
 @dispatches = Dispatch.find_by_message_ids(CODE TO RETRIEVE CHECKBOX ARRAY GOES HERE)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried inspecting the value of `params`?

Chances are this will work:

```
@dispatches = Dispatch.find_by_message_ids(params[:message_ids])
```

But if it doesn't, just look at what is being sent to your page. Try one of these:

```
logger.info(params)
```

or

```
raise (params.inspect)
```

or

```
render :inline => params.to_yaml
```

Comment: @Jonah My name isn't "meager", also: `@dispatches = Dispatch.find_by_message_ids(params[:message_ids]) if params[:message_ids]`

Comment: Sorry about that! And i actually got it to work by adding an `unless params[:message_ids].blank?` but thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jonah I normally hate when people do this, but: Upvotes are the accepted way of saying "thanks".

Comment: Ofcourse! I went to accept before but it "accept in 9 minutes" Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Check what you receive in your `params` because they're probably there if this is defined correctly. The current parameters are always logged in `log/development.log` which is something you should have open any time you're debugging something.